# Communicate between Packages in Java

Tags: java

I've a problem that concerns the communication between Packages.
This is the question, is it possible to have a list in a package and import this list into another package, so that i can use it there too?

This is the code:

```
// this is the first package where i create the list and i've create a method to return the       list
package Pack1;
import java.util.*;

public class Lexer 
  {
     public static LinkedList<Object> lst  = new LinkedList<Object>();

     public static LinkedList<Object> getList(){
        return lst;
        }
  } 

    // After this, i add objects to "lst", so the list it's full of objects.
 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//This is the second Package. 
package Pack2;

import Pack1.*;
import java.util.*;

 public class Parse {

//In the main i tried to create a List to contain the old one ("lst") but when i use the 
    //method getList nothing happens! So toString prints nothing.

public static void main(String[] args )
   {
    LinkedList<Object> list = new LinkedList<Object>();
    list = Lexer.getList();
    list.toString();
   }

}
```

Comment: _is it possible to have a list in a package and import this list into another package_ No, because you can't have a list in a package :P

Comment: Why you have 2 packages for that? You should have the 2 classes on same package

Comment: Thank you for the answer but, for me it's the first time on Stackoverflow, so can i ask u why i cannot have a list in a package?

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: Keppil the problem is that it's not working.

Comment: There can be only one package statement in each source file, and it applies to all types in the file.

Comment: _It's not working_ doesn't tell us anything. Do you get any errors? In what way isn't it working?

Comment: careexcer i have too because this is a Project for my University and they told me to use 2 packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`import` just allows you to refer to a class, or field without needing to use the full package name.  It doesn't give to access to something you didn't have access to already.  It just makes your code shorter.

If you want to pass a `list` from one class to another (whether in another package or not) the simplest approach is to call a method and pass a reference with that `list`.

What you are doing is using a global field. While that can work it is generally not a good idea as it makes scaling and testing your application harder.

Instead I suggest you avoid mutable static fields, and use a instance field instead.  I also suggest avoiding returning a collection.  If you need to to string a list add a method like

```
public String listToString() {
    return list.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible for a *class* in a package to give a list (or any other object) to a class in a different package. In fact, your code should work, assuming you have those two packages in two different files in the folders `Pack1` and `Pack2` (which you should make non-capitals for code styling reasons)

Comment: Sorry for the non-capitol but i've modified the code at the moment, anyway  it's a must for me to have my program stored in this way, a main Directory and inside it the parsing package and the Lexer Package

Comment: No worries on the caps ;) As to the directories, as far as I know, you do not have a choice. The package declaration must match the directory structure, so you'll need each class in its place..

Comment: they are, i think, cause Lexer is in Pack1 and Parse is in Pack2 and Pack1 and 2 are in the main Dir. of the project

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of the code it's hard to say but my guess is the code you use to populate your list isn't being executed so you're just getting a `new LinkedList<Object>()` back. Show us the code where you populate the list.

Answer (score 0):

A rather strange answer, but as far as I can tell there's no problem in passing references between instances of classes from different package branches.

Package confinement is only for class members: methods, fields, constructors. But this has nothing to do by passing objects by reference as long as the reference type is visible across different packages, e.g. `java.util.*` classes.

Regarding your problem `list.toString()` is only returning you an object representation in string, but ***does not*** by any means prints it to your console or any other I/O.

What you need in order to print it to console is `System.out.println( list )` Java will put a call to `toString()` implicitly